# difference between arrow operator (->) and array index bracket([]) in php

Tags: php, laravel, annotations, operators

What is exactly the difference between arrow operator -> and array indexing bracket[] ?

In my experience if we can do `$obj->item;` we always can do `$obj['item'];`

But not the other ways around.

Comment: `->` is for objects and `[]` is for arrays and objects that implement [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) so no they are not interchangeable

Answer (score 3):

You can use brackets with array but you cant use arrow for arrays. Array is data structure but object is stdClass in PHP. So, you can use object is like a normal class. You can use both for objects.